# jQuery - Cycle Plugin - Image Positioning

Tags: jquery, cycle

I am using the jQuery Cycle plugin to rotate a series of images on this [site](http://www.rouviere.com/aav/index.html). The images look nice in Safari but they are off about 4 pixels at the top in Firefox. Obviously with the intersecting line there it is rather critical to keep the positioning right.

I would appreciate some help in positioning that element so that the cycle.js does not move it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that it was a conflict between the floated elements and the absolute positioning of the cycle code.

I replaced it with another solution that actually works fine.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
        setInterval("rotateImages()", 4000 );
    });

    function rotateImages() {
        var oCurPhoto = $("#slideshow div.current");
        var oNxtPhoto = oCurPhoto.next();
        if (oNxtPhoto.length == 0)
            oNxtPhoto = $("#slideshow div:first");

        oCurPhoto.removeClass('current').addClass('previous');
        oNxtPhoto.css({ opacity: 0.0 }).addClass('current').animate({ opacity: 1.0 }, 2000, 
            function() {
                oCurPhoto.removeClass('previous');
            }); 
}
</script>
```